# General solution of $x'=ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the first chapter of "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems and an Introduction to Chaos" by Hirch, Smale and Devaney, the authors mention the first-order equation $x'(t)=ax(t)$ and assert that the only general solution to it is $x(t)=ke^{at}$. The assertion is proven by deriving $u(t)e^{-at}$ to show that it is the constant $k$ in the general solution mentioned.

My question is that, how did the authors initially arrive at the asserted solution? Because they didn't explain it in the book.

Comment: 1. Separation of variables. Or 2. Guessing the solution and checking it.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that under the table the author's is using without saying Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem.

Comment: @jacopoburelli It seems the proof just assumes $u$ is (another) solution and then noting the derivative of $u(t)e^{-at}$ is identically $0$; which gives the uniqueness result. (So, avoiding the more general uniqueness theorem).

Comment: @DavidMitra I agree, can be done without it. Felt like worth mentioning.

Comment: If one is familiar with basic functions and their derivatives, a bit of reflection would suggest $ke^{at}$ is a solution.

Comment: Just *solve* the ODE using the integrating factor $e^{-at}$...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the equation can be rewritten of the form
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a*x$$

divide by x
$$\frac{dx}{x*dt}=a$$

multiply both sides by $dt$

it becomes
$$\frac{dx}{x}=a*dt$$

Now,
integrate both sides

becomes:

ln(x)=at.

take   e to both sides
$$x=x_0 e^{at}$$

$x_0$ is your initial  data

Comment: This isn't quite correct. What if $x_0 \le 0$?

Comment: Rather than $ln(x)=at$, it should be $ln|x|=at$. This should at least address the $x_0<0$ part of the scenario that Hans brought up.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good question!

For the first order equation $x'(t) = a x(t)$, where $a$ is a constant, we can rewrite it as a homogeneous first order ODE, namely
$$
(D - a) x(t) = 0 \tag{1}
$$
where $D = {d \over dt}$, the differential operator.

For (1), the auxiliary equation (or subsidiary equation) is given by
$$
m - a = 0
$$
which has the real root $m = a$.

(The auxiliary equation is obtained by considering a trial solution $x(t) = e^{m t}$ and noting that $D e^{m t} = m e^{m t}$. This is a standard procedure in solving homogeneous ordinary differential equations.)

Hence, the solution space of (1) will consist of $e^{a t}$ as a basis solution.

Thus, we consider any general solution of (1) as
$$
x(t) = k e^{a t},
$$
where $k$ is an integration constant. It is easy to check that
$$
x(0) = k (1) 
$$
so that we can express the unique solution of (1) satisfying $x(0) = x_0$ as
$$
x(t) = x_0 e^{a t}
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the auxiliary equation and how, from there, you concluded that the solution space would consist of $e^{at}$?